# Unity how to pass Request in Controller's constructor from Unity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container, moq

The old controller code with Concrete dependencies:

```
public SomeController: Controller
{    
    public SomeController()
    {
    }

    public ActionResult Default()
    {
        **Something something = new Something(Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL"].ToString());**
        something.SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

The new Controller code with TDD focus:

```
public SomeControllerNew: Controller
{

    private readonly ISomething _something;

    public SomeControllerNew(ISomething something)
    {
        _something = something;
    }

    public ActionResult Default()
    {
        _something.SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM:**
Now in new TDD approach i need to invoke constructor where I am registering the Interface. I have put it in UnityBootstraper common file, Something like:
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType();

```
**Something something = new Something(Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL"].ToString());**
        something.SomeMethod();
```

This is not working here. Error is quite clear:
Object reference required for non-static field, method, property 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Request.get'.

I can't figure out how i can access http request here in UnityBootstrapper?

Edit:
    Trying to do all this in RegisterRoutes.

```
 public class RouteConfig
    {        
       public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
       {
              DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new Unity.Mvc3.UnityDependencyResolver(UnityBootstrapper.Initialise()));
              var container = new UnityContainer();
                container.RegisterType<ISometing, Something>();
       }
    }
```

Comment: What are you using for a [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/)? A custom `IControllerFactory`? Can you show your composition root?

Comment: For now I am directly doing it in RouteConfig.
public class RouteConfig
{
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
   {
          var container = new UnityContainer();
            container.RegisterType<ISometing, Something>();
   }
}

Comment: I have editted the original post with this information too.

Comment: How does the MVC framework know about the container? Are you using DependencyResolver? Or are you creating a custom `IControllerFactory`?

Comment: I am using DependencyResolver. By mistake, I skipped it. I have editted it now.

Comment: Prevent using and injecting runtime data (like your `ServerVariables["HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL"]`) into your components; it's an [anti-pattern](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to create an abstract factory like this:

```
public interface ISomethingFactory
{
    ISomething Create(string url);
}

public class SomethingFactory : ISomethingFactory
{
    public ISomething Create(string url)
    {
        return new Something(url);
    }
}
```

And make your controller depend on it like this:

```
public class SomeControllerNew: Controller
{
    private readonly ISomething _something;

    public SomeControllerNew(ISomethingFactory somethingFactory)
    {
        _something = somethingFactory.Create(Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL"].ToString();
    }

    public ActionResult Default()
    {
        _something.SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

A better approach (IMO) is to use a custom Controller Factory instead of using the Dependency Resolver like this:

```
public class CustomFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        var request = requestContext.HttpContext.Request; //Here we have access to the request

        if (controllerName == "Some") //Name of controller
        {
            //Use the container to resolve and return the controller.
            //When you resolve, you can use ParameterOverride to specify the value of the string dependency that you need to inject into Something
        }

        return base.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
    }
}
```

This way you don't have to introduce the `ISomethingFactory`, and your controller would still depend on `ISomething` directly.

You would need to tell the MVC framework about this custom controller factory like this (in `Application_Start`):

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new CustomFactory());
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what should I write in the if condition. I think it would come here from "requestContext.HttpContext.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL"].ToString()" but I can't figure out how should Concrete instance and pass this request variable?

Comment: I have given it a try like:
if(controllerName == "myController")
{
   var something = new Something(request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL"]);
   var commonOpnRepository = new CommonOperationsRepository();
   return new UsedController(commonOpnRepository, deviceDetection);
}

Is it the correct way to do?

Comment: Without using the container, you would put something like this: `return new SomeControllerNew(new Something(request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL"].ToString()))`

Comment: Since you are using a container, you need to move the container to this class. That is, create some instance variable to hold the container, and create a constructor for `CustomFactory` and in this constructor make all of your registrations. And then inside the if statement, use the container to resolve an instance of `SomeControllerNew`. You would need to override the string dependency by using `ParameterOverride`. You can find a lot of examples online of how to use `ParameterOverride`.

Comment: Yes, this is a correct way and it is called [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/). But you can still use the container if you want to.